# Add a proxy to a particular host only in mac

Tags: macos, proxy

I want to apply proxy settings to a particular host only (e.g., www.apple.com) in Mac OS X.
How can I do it?

In System Preferences there are only options for *bypassing* proxy settings for particular hosts.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use the following `proxy.pac` file to send all traffic to apple.com through the proxy 1.2.3.4 while still going directly to all other hosts:

```
function FindProxyForURL(url, host) {
    PROXY = "PROXY 1.2.3.4"

    // Apple.com via proxy
    if (shExpMatch(host,"*.apple.com")) {
        return PROXY;
    }
    // Everything else directly!
    return "DIRECT";
}
```

1. Save this script as `proxy.pac`(or any other name you like) on a web server. This can be a local web server (http://localhost/proxy.pac). This is [required as of OSX Lion](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3202499).
2. Go to the `System Preferences`.
3. Select `Network`.
4. Select the network you want to change (i.e. "WiFi").
5. Click `Advanced...` button.
6. Click `Proxies` tab
7. Check `[x] Automatic Proxy-Configuration`.
8. In the `URL:` field, type in the URL to the file you've created in step 1., for example: `http://localhost/proxy.pac`. (note: local paths will not work in modern OSX)
9. Click `Save` and `Apply`

Voila! Your own proxy-configuration

For more information on the format of the `proxy.pac` file have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_Auto-Config as starting point.

Answer (score 13):

Actually you can use the `file:///path/to/file` scheme for the URL, instead of having to rely on a web server.

For example:

```
file:///Users/youruser/var/proxy/proxy.pac
```

Comment: Interestingly this all works for Linux/BSD as well, and possibly even Windows; anywhere _Automatic Proxy Configuration_ is used, this is likely to work.

Comment: This should probably be the accepted answer as it avoids overcomplicating the stack in use and as the previous comment mentions - is a far more universal solution.

Comment: If you use file:///...pac, then in some applications you can have issues (e.g. Microsoft apps like Teams and others, see https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4042151/outlook-2016-for-mac-crash-when-a-proxy-auto-configuration-file-used), so the best way is to put it on localhost or any public server on the Internet.

Comment: This does NOT work on OSX.

Comment: @jpgeek works on 10.15 for me. If you're not sure, return `'PROXY ...'` without checking for domain to verify. `proxy.pac` gets re-read when you toggle wifi.

Comment: @seeker_of_bacon Thx for comment.  I am on 10.15.3, but does not work.  In pac file tried return "PROXY..." but still does direct connection.  Tried entering non-existent pac file path but shows no error and connects directly (80, 443 etc).

Comment: By `'PROXY ...'` I mean actual address to your proxy. I have `'PROXY localhost:9050'`, since I have tor on that port.

Comment: This does not appear to work on macOS Catalina. I am getting "Unsupported PAC URL scheme - please use HTTP or HTTPS for PAC File URLs" in the system logs.

Comment: Since this answer was posted, Chrome 72 (2019) has disabled support for loading Proxy PAC files from `file:///` URLs. https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=839566

Answer (score 3):

Adding to @heiglandreas's answer...

@jnbek's solution did not work on Mac OSX for me and I was looking for a simple solution.

So, I created a new folder and copied the pac file into that.
Then, I started a simple web server on OSX on port 80 from that folder itself.

Just go into the folder & run this command.
Please change the port from 80 to something else if its already occupied.

`python -m SimpleHTTPServer 80`

Now, I could easily get the proxy.pac file from `http://localhost/proxy.pac`. 
Or, for different port use: `http://localhost:PORT/proxy.pac`.

Answer (score 1):

@Rehmat's answer is great, but it's not updated for python 3 and Mac OS X Big Sur:

1. Create a proxy.pac file in a new directory called proxy-web (in whatever parent directory you want):

   ```javascript
   function FindProxyForURL(url, host) {
       PROXY = "PROXY 1.2.3.4"

       // Apple.com via proxy
       if (shExpMatch(host,"*.apple.com")) {
           return PROXY;
       }
       // Everything else directly!
       return "DIRECT";
   }
   ```
2. Start a web server in that directory where your proxy.pac file is located

   ```bsh
   cd proxy-web
   ls
   # proxy.pac
   python -m http.server 80
   ```
3. Open Apple -> System Preferences
4. Click Network
5. Select the specific network in question (ex: "Thunderbolt Ethernet" or "Wi-Fi")
6. Click Advanced
7. Select the Proxies tab
8. Check the Automatic Proxy Configuration box, input URL: http://localhost/proxy.pac
9. Click OK and Apply but do not close network settings
10. Test that it's working by going to apple in CHROME (not SAFARI -- for me, our corporate URLs and proxy did not seem to work in Safari but Chrome worked just fine): [apple.com](https://apple.com)
11. Test in Safari. If it's not working click "Renew DHCP Lease" under the `Advanced → TCP/IP` tab back in network settings
12. Run further tests in your favorite browser by going to non-apple URIs (ex: [google.com](https://google.com)). If you're proxying a specific subdomain, you'll also want to test other subdomains that are not supposed to be proxied.